# Use Data Module Events in Other Form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a idudpserver in a Data Module and link this DM to a server Form.
My server form uses this data module. When client sent message from udp port to server, IdUDPServer1UDPRead event in datamodule is raised but I must use this event in server to write result in server's memo. How can I do that?

My data module must be completely independent from server.

Answer (score 3):

Add an event property to the datamodule which can be set from your server form.
If assigned call it from the datamodule.

e.g. datamodule

```
type
  TCallBackMessage=Procedure (Sender:TObject;const msg:String) of object;

  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    Event: TTimer; // just for test
    procedure EventEvent(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCallBackMessage: TCallBackMessage;
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    Property CallBack:TCallBackMessage read FCallBackMessage Write FCallBackMessage;
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDataModule2.EventEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if Assigned(CallBack) then CallBack(self,'MyMessage')

end;
```

Server

```
procedure TForm1.MyCallBack(Sender: TObject; const Msg: String);
begin
  Showmessage('Hallo')
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(Datamodule2.CallBack) then
    Datamodule2.CallBack := MyCallBack;
end;
```

Comment: @Mohammad: If this answer helped you solve your issue, you may consider accepting it as "the" answer. Thanks. Info: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)